# Azure container apps not taking Azure Cosmos DB for Table connection string

Tags: azure, azure-container-apps, azure-cosmosdb-tables

I have an application running on Azure container apps that uses Azure Cosmos DB for Table to store customer's feedback. Azure Cosmos DB for Table connection string has been added to as a secret to the container apps, but I get "connection string parsing error".

I expected customer feedback to successfully populate in the cosmos DB for table. I have checked the container environment variable value to make sure it matches the connection string secret key.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi Richard, could you share some code? configuration ? so we can try to reproduce your issue

Comment: Under the container app properties in bicep, I exported the cosmos db table connection string with: 
 properties: {
    configuration: {
      secrets: [ {
          name: 'cosdb-connection-string'
          value: cosmacc_existing.listConnectionStrings().connectionStrings[0].connectionString}]

But I noticed the connection string format being exported is different from the connection string seen directly on the cosmosdb db in the portal.